# Anychart Series Custom Drawing with Json

Tags: json, drawing, series, renderer, anychart

We build our chart using a Json config and load it using anychart.fromJson(). This works quite well so far, but is it also possible to use it for Custom Drawing?
For Custom Drawing I have to pass a drawer function to series.rendering() like so:

`series.rendering().point(drawer).updatePoint(drawer);`

Example: https://playground.anychart.com/docs/v8/samples/BCT_Custom_Drawing_03

I'm looking for a way to do this **within the Json config**. Is this even possible?

Or do I have to get the series object from the chart after I created the chart with anychart.fromJson()?
Or is there perhaps a completely different way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible via JSON because JSON format doesn't support functions. But you can apply the custom drawing function using JS API after parsing JSON. For details, check [the sample](https://playground.anychart.com/8EpUIQHu).

Comment: Thanks for the example. It's finally working!
But I still have one small question. I would like to fill the triangles with a (background) color and a hatch fill at the same time. I get the hatch with
shape.fill(anychart.graphics.hatchFill(hatchFill.type, hatchFill.color, hatchFill.thickness, hatchFill.size)) but it overwrites the color of the series. Can I set a series color at the same time?

Comment: You can apply hatchfill using the series API, there's no need to modify the path shape fill settings. For details, check the modified sample (line 24) - https://playground.anychart.com/5wSNQJFz/0

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I wanted.